# 2 points outside the circle and the shortest path connected both of them while touching the circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose you have a circle and two points (A and B) outside the circle in the cartesian plane. The question is to find the shortest path from A to B while touching the perimeter of the circle.

1. Is there straightforward formula to find this shortest path value (distance)?
2. How to find the point V where the the shortest path touches?
3. Are the angles alpha and beta equal if the given segments form the shortest path?

Edit:
Points C,A,B and R (radius) are given

[image]

Comment: This is Alhazen's problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961401/alhazens-problem-history/3963600#3963600

Comment: Yes, the two angles are equal, because when you find a point $V$ with this property the distance $AV+VB$ is the shortest path from $A$ to $B$ that touches the tangent line, and since every other point on the circle is on the "other  side" of the tangent line the path via that point will be even longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a moving point $V$ on the circumference of the given circle, the total distance is

$ D = AV + BV = \| V - A \| + \| V - B \| \\ = \sqrt{(V(\phi) - A)\cdot(V(\phi) - A)} + \sqrt{(V(\phi)-B)\cdot(V(\phi)-B)} $

where $\phi$ is the central angle of $V$ from a fixed ray originating at the center $C$.

Take the derivative of $d$ with respect to $\phi$, then

$ \dfrac{dD}{d\phi} = V'(\phi) \cdot \left( \dfrac{ (V - A)}{\| V - A \|} + \dfrac{ (V-B)}{\|V-B\|} \right) $

Now $V'(\phi)$ (the $\phi$ derivative of $V$ ) is tangential to the circle.  And what this equation means is that the tangent vector at $V$ is perpendicualar to the sum of these two unit vectors.  Since this sum is a vector that bisects the angle between them, then we conclude that at the minimum distance $D$, the normal vector to the circle bisects the rays $VA$ and $VB$.

Next, we will find the location of this point $V$.

Let $Y = \angle ACB $, and let $x = \angle ACV$, and let $\alpha = \dfrac{1}{2} \angle AVB $

Applying the law of sines to $\triangle ACV $ and $\triangle BCV$ and noting that $ \angle VAC = \alpha - x $ and $\angle VBC = \alpha - (Y - x) $, we get,

$ \dfrac{ \sin(\alpha - x) }{r} = \dfrac{\sin(\alpha) }{CA} $

and

$ \dfrac{ \sin(\alpha - (Y-x)) }{r} = \dfrac{\sin(\alpha) }{CB} $

After expanding $\sin(\alpha - x)$, we get

$ \tan(\alpha) = \dfrac{ \sin(x) }{\cos(x) - r / CA } $

Similarly from the second equation, we get

$ \tan(\alpha) = \dfrac{ \sin(Y-x) }{\cos(Y-x) - r/ CB} $

Equating the two and cross multiplying gives us

$ \sin(x) (\cos(Y-x) - \dfrac{r}{CB} ) = \sin(Y - x) (\cos(x) - \dfrac{r}{CA} ) $

Expanding $\cos(Y-x)$ and $\sin(Y - x)$ gives

$ \sin(x) ( \cos(Y) \cos(x) + \sin(Y) \sin(x) - \dfrac{r}{CB} ) = (\sin(Y) \cos(x) - \cos(Y) \sin(x) ) (\cos(x) - \dfrac{r}{CA} ) $

Collecting terms,

$ [\dfrac{r}{CA} \sin(Y)] \cos(x) + [-\cos(Y) \dfrac{r}{CA} -\dfrac{r}{CB}] \sin(x) + \sin(Y) ( \sin^2(x) - \cos^2(x) ) +  \cos(Y) \sin(2 x) = 0 $

And this reduces further to

$ [\dfrac{r}{CA} \sin(Y) ] \cos(x) + [-\cos(Y) \dfrac{r}{CA} -\dfrac{r}{CB} ] \sin(x) + [ - \sin(Y) ] \cos(2x) + [\cos(Y)] \sin(2x) = 0 $

which is an equation of the form

$ A \cos(x) + B \sin(x) + C \cos(2x) + D \sin(2x) = 0 $

It is not straightforward nor easy to obtain the solution of this equation.  The solution is through introducing a change of variable by the substitution $z = \tan\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) $.  This is a well-known substitution, with which we can express $\cos(x), \sin(x)$ as follows:

$\cos(x) = \dfrac{1 - z^2}{1 + z^2} $

$ \sin(x) = \dfrac{2z}{1 + z^2} $

And using the fact that $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x) $ and that $\cos(2x) = 2 \cos^2(x) - 1 $, we substitute this rational expressions in $z$ into the trigonometric equation to obtain a rational function in $z$.  Multiplying through by the common denominator gives a numerator which is a degree $4$ polynomial in $z$.  The next step is to find the roots of this polynomial, and this is possible using known formulas for the roots of degree $4$ polynomial.  But implementing the formulas is not trivial at all.  Once the roots are found, the angles can retrieved from the roots by the formula $ \theta = 2 \tan^{-1}(z) $.  It is easy to exclude extraneous values of $\theta$ given the expected range which is $[0, Y]$.

That said, it is best to utilize a math app to find the roots of the trigonometric equation above.

Or, you could also, solve numerically using a simple and straightforward method which is the well-celebrated **Newton's Method**.  The method is quite easy to use, and all you need is to determine the derivative of the trigonometric function above.

**Numerical Example:**

With $C = (3,9), A = (0,0), B = (8,0),r = 5$ and using the above outlined procedure, we get the following figure for the shortest path.  The cyan segment shows that the normal to the circle bisects $\angle AVB$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Angles of reflection and incidence $(\alpha,\beta)$ are equal, as a consequence of Fermat's Law (that minimizes total time of travel AV+VB) in Optics.

Let $(x,y)=(x_V,y_V)$

Dot products of the vectors are equal

$$\left((xC-x)+(yC-y)i\right)\cdot \left((xA-x)+(yA-y)i\right) =$$

$$\left((xC-x)+(yC-y)i\right)\cdot \left((xB-x)+(yB-y)i\right) ;$$

is one condition, the reflector mirror circle equation is known at start.

If these equations are felt analytically to be too heavy, numerical solution may be resorted to.

Comment: I edited the question saying that you know C A B and the radius of the circle. So you know the circle equation.

Comment: OK,  was also clear from the diagram in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the ellipses with focii $A$ and $B$. When such an ellipse is tangent to the circle the minumum sum condition is achived. And the normal of the tangency point bisects the angle from the focii.